# Any way to disable Ruby on Rails app hosted by Heroku for a while in order to stop monthly payments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, payment, offline

I've got a website I created using Ruby on Rails and DNSimple hosting/management, deployed on Heroku. Since it's still not ready for production yet and I'm paying $20 monthly for the SSL endpoint, is there any way to take it offline for a few months in order to stop being charged monthly for it, without having to configure SSL for both Heroku and DNSimple plus re-deploy again once it's ready for public use? Even better would be if I could temporarily stop the DNSimple monthly payments as well ($8.00 a month) since the app won't even be hosted or running/accessed by anyone, if this is at all feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku charge per dyno hours, there is a free tier, anything that pass that is charged, to avoid being charged by Heroku you can reduce to one 1X Dyno and no Workers or Clocks or if you wanna take down your app you can reduce to 0 dynos.

You can reduce in the Heroku dashboard, to do so go to http://heroku.com, login, and select your application, once on the application click in edit and reduce the number of dynos to 1 or 0.

About the DNSimple you can cancel your subscription and active again when you need if you have used your trial. More info about cancel the DNSimple can be found [here](http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/cancel-subscription/).

Comment: Thanks ooredroxoo. I reduced the Dynos to 0 and then removed the SSL addon in my app's Heroku settings, which has brought my total amount owed to "$0.00" :)   Haven't cancelled the DNSimple subscription yet but will do ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can disable DNSimple altogether and use CloudFlare (https://www.cloudflare.com) for SSL - they have a free option.

Comment: If I transferred my domain over to DNSimple from HostGator where I originally registered it, how can I setup CloudFlare for my site's DNS & SSL  for free (with Heroku) without continuing to pay DNSimple a monthly fee for anything? Do I have to transfer domain ownership back to a different place now?

Comment: @hworth you will have to point your domain's name servers to CloudFlare. It's very simple. Here is some more info (http://support.hostgator.com/articles/pre-sales-questions/what-is-cloudflare) and instructions (https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171656-How-do-I-change-my-nameservers-at-HostGator-)

Comment: my domain is now owned by DNSimple, not HostGator anymore. Can I still use the free DNS option offered by CloudFlare?

Comment: @hworth, you'll have to transfer it from DNSimple. You may have to go to HostGator first and transfer your name servers from DNSimple back to HostGator. Then you can transfer them to CloudFlare.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale down your dynos and web workers to 0 to avoid getting charged for them. However, I think you'll still be charged for any paid addons such as SSL.

Comment: You are correct, it appears that the DNS addon has to be removed in order to eliminate all monthly payments owed to Heroku (I was required to do "certs:remove" first before the service would allow me to remove DNS from my app's dash on Heroku.com)